# how to know the default file path for memcache. Am using php mysql

Tags: php, memcached

how to know the default file path for memcache. Am using php mysql 
Is dr any provision to change the default file path user defined path

Comment: memcached is a daemon, what path are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

agreed, why do you care about this? it's a service running, you don't need to care where the operating system stores files on disk.  Just make sure you have the service installed and running.  And then just interface with the [php api](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.memcache.php) and you're good to go.  [Here's](http://papermashup.com/using-memcache-with-php/) a simple example as well.